# Facing issues while using spring cassandra - UDT Type, not able to map udt type to udtvalue

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, mapping

Could not inline literal of type AddressUDT. This happens because the driver doesn't know how to map it to a CQL type. Try passing a TypeCodec or CodecRegistry to literal().; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not inline literal of type AddressUDT. This happens because the driver doesn't know how to map it to a CQL type. Try passing a TypeCodec or CodecRegistry to literal().",

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a custom converter so Cassandra knows how to map your UDT to a CQL type.

You need to create a class that extends `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` to do custom conversions. Have a look at the [Spring Data documentation on Custom Converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.custom-converters) for details and examples. Cheers!